# Using model map attribute in FTL's Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, web, freemarker

Im using FTL for my front end . I send some objects from model map like this

```
model.addAttribute("xxx","myDetails");
```

But when i try to access it in a inline javascript inside an ftl file like this :

```
$('#someDiv').html({xxx});
```

But it cannot be accessed.Can anyone give me solution to access . I m very new to ftl so someone help me out with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the dollar

```
$('#someDiv').html(${xxx});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since FreeMarker runs on the server, you have to generate text that's valid JavaScript:

```
$('#someDiv').html("${xxx?js_string}")
```

The `?js_string` is needed if there can be characters in `xxx` that have to be escaped in a JavaScript string literals.